# Regular expression extract username from domain

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a list of systems on my domain. They are supposed to be named after the user. There is a prefix with a dash the username and possibly some numbers or dashes after.

Here is my source string:

```
PL-USERNAME1-7.corp.domain.com
cd-USERNAME03.corp.domain.com
ul-USERNAME.corp.domain.com
HID-USERNAME203.corp.domain.com
```

I just want to match / extract `USERNAME`

I just have:

```
(([A-Z])+-)
```

EDIT:

I want mixed case usernames as well.

Comment: What characters are accepted for the username?

Comment: Only letters mixed case which can be padded with numbers and dashes before and after.

CD-101TRAIN18.corp.domain.com  I would just want TRAIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
^\w+-([A-Z]+)
```

It will match:

```
^       # The start of the string
\w+     # One or more word characters (the prefix)
-       # -
[A-Z]+  # One or more letters (the username)
```

Demo:

```
PS > $str = @"
PL-USERNAME1-7.corp.domain.com
cd-USERNAME03.corp.domain.com
ul-USERNAME.corp.domain.com
HID-USERNAME203.corp.domain.com
"@
PS > foreach ($line in $str.Split("`n")) {
         $line -match '^\w+-([A-Z]+)' > $null
         $Matches[1]
     }
USERNAME
USERNAME
USERNAME
USERNAME
PS >
```

Comment: Are you sure the username will only contain capital letters? OP didn't say that

Comment: '^\w+-([A-Z]+)' seems works great but how do I add mixed alpha case?

Comment: @BradleySmith - Just add `a-z` to the character set.  This will allow you to match lowercase as well.  See my edit.

Comment: @SanD - I used `[A-Z]` because that was in the OP's original pattern.  Either way, adding `a-z` to the character set is easy enough.

Comment: @iCodez yes, it is easy, but I opted for allowing any characters in the username, including digits and punctuation, why did you choose to be so restrictive?

Comment: @SanD - Because the OP never said that the usernames would contain anything but letters.  In addition, his old pattern was matching `[A-Z]`, which seems to hint that there are only letters.  I was keeping the pattern as simple as it needs to be.  If the OP changes the requirements, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: iCodez answered it. Thank you SanD as well! This is my first post and I'm not sure hot to marked it answered. I tried to click the up triangle but I don't have enough rep. LOL

Comment: Found another example where it isn't working. 
CD-110ThMulti25.corp.domian.com 
When there is a number before (which I want ignored) it doesn't match.

Comment: @BradleySmith - That's because I based my pattern off of the examples you had in your question (which didn't have leading numbers).  You can handle these cases however by inserting `\d*` in the pattern: `^\w+-\d*([A-Za-z]+)`.  It will match zero or more digit characters.

Comment: JFTR, PowerShell matches are case-insensitive by default, so `'^\w+-([a-z]+)'` does cover mixed-case as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^[^-]+-(.*?)[-0-9]*\.corp\.domain\.com$
```

Username will be in the first capturing group

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/kE9jJ5/1)

Comment: I tried your example however I got an error in powerhsell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming theres no `.` in the user name the most readable bit of Regex I could come up with was:

```
(?<=-)[^.]*
PL-USERNAME1-7.corp.domain.com -MATCHES- PL-USERNAME1-7
cd-USERNAME03.corp.domain.com -MATCHES- cd-USERNAME03
ul-USERNAME.corp.domain.com -MATCHES- ul-USERNAME
HID-USERNAME203.corp.domain.com -MATCHES- HID-USERNAME203
```

What the regex is doing is essentially matching anything after the `-` that isnt a `.`

Comment: What I wanted to do is "extract" the just the username not just match it. But thanks for the reply!